# django internationalization didn't work on webfaction

Tags: python, django, internationalization, web-deployment

I have a Django project that works fine on my local server but when I 
deploy it to web faction, internationalization doesn't work anymore. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify _doesn't work anymore_.

Comment: thank you for your attention,it works now i was passing wrong url to LOCALE_PATHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works now i was passing wrong url to LOCALE_PATHS